# uintmax_t not handling 128 bits

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, primitive-types

I wanted to define gigabyte in my code so I used, firstly, `unsigned long`. However, `unsigned long` could not handle `2 * gigabyte`.

So, I replaced it with `long long` but I got the same compilation error/warning:
    error: integer overflow in expression [-Werror=overflow]

Finally, I looked up for big integers and found that uintmax_t is what I need as it is 128 bits.

Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error. I guess there is a small fault but I could find it.

Please find below the relevant code:

```
#define kilobyte 1024
#define megabyte 1024 * kilobyte
#define gigabyte 1024 * megabyte
uintmax_t threshold = 2 * gigabyte;
```

Finally, after running 'make'

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -pthread -std=c++0x -g  -o lcr main.cpp
```

I got:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:104:17: error: integer overflow in expression [-Werror=overflow]
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Comment: .. what about using contans instead of macros? Maybe then you'll see the problem?

Comment: Define constant is a bad practice

Comment: @DieterLücking Thank you for your critic, what would you suggest?

Comment: @Moi same as Columbo suggests

Comment: @Moi See my updated answer, the last code snippet :)

Comment: Please look into the header file `<cstdint>` to find the maximum range for the integer types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at a piece of code:

```
uintmax_t x = 2 * 1024;
```

What happens here, is we have `(int) 2 * (int) 1024`, and then we promote the result to `uintmax_t`.

Instead, we want: `(uintmax_t) 2 * (uintmax_t) 1024`. We can easily promote the integers to `long long` via this method:

```
#define kilobyte 1024ULL
#define megabyte 1024ULL * kilobyte
#define gigabyte 1024ULL * megabyte
uintmax_t threshold = 2ULL * gigabyte;
```

Answer (score 5):

The product of two `int`s is clearly still of type `int` - and the literals we're dealing with in your macros are of type `int`.
*1024<sup>3</sup> = 2<sup>30</sup>* is just about representable in a 32-bit `int`. However, *2*2<sup>30</sup> = 2<sup>31</sup>* is exactly one too large for a 32-bit signed `int` to hold.

This can be solved by defining the constants as objects of appropriate type:

```
const std::uintmax_t kilobyte = 1024;
const std::uintmax_t megabyte = 1024 * kilobyte;
const std::uintmax_t gigabyte = 1024 * megabyte;
const std::uintmax_t threshold = 2 * gigabyte;
```

Thanks to the usual arithmetic conversions being performed on operands of `*`, no overflow can occur.